# How to Edit margins in EPSON TM-T88 Receipt Printer

Tags: vb.net, epson

I'm using vb.net programming language. Also, suggest me any solution to work around if I can't change top and/or bottom margin.

Comment: Have you considered the fact that the cutting head requires a certain amount of feed so it doesn't chop up your receipt?

Comment: @JustinRyan: ya, I have checked gap between cutter and printer head, but still I thought any other solution to work around, that's why I posted it for seeking alternate solution if any.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the question is already a little bit old, but an answer may be of interest for other people as well.
Controlling the upper and lower margins is quite limited, due to the fact we are dealing with a line printer here (opposed to a page printer like the typical inkjet or laser printer).
But if you are using TM-T88V, you should take a look at the ARP (Automatic Reduction of Paper) functions of the printer. With these you can reduce the upper and lower margins of a print-out to the minimum. You can configure it using the TM-Utility available on http://http://download.epson-biz.com/.